# Calling a SQL Server stored procedure and one of the variables in a file that will be inserted into table

Tags: sql-server

Calling a stored procedure from VB 2008 into a SQL Server database. Passing several variables of which one is a file name with full path.

I am having hard time for the stored procedure to take the file and create a BLOB out of it and insert it into one of the fields in table

Incoming variables:

```
    @myProduct      Varchar(20),
    @myVersion      Varchar(20),
    --@myFileName   Varchar(50),
    @myPath         Varchar(100),
    @myStatus       Varchar(15),
    @myDeviceType   VarChar(50),
    @myAction       Varchar(50),
    @shortName      Varchar(50),
    @myBlob         VarBinary(Max)
```

Here is the insert:

```
INSERT INTO schema.tablename
VALUES (@myProduct, @myVersion, @myAction, NULL,
        @myPath, @myBlob, myDeviceType, @Shortname)
```

I tried putting

```
SELECT BulkColumn 
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK @myblob, SINGLE_CLOB) @lBlob
```

and changing `@myBlob` with `@lBlob`.

I am getting:

> Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not
>   allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Any help?

Comment: What is the data type of the column ?

Comment: I would recommend to **always** explicitly **specify** the columns you're inserting into in your `INSERT` statement - that way , you can match which values is supposed to go into which column, and it should become quite clear where the error happens. Also makes your code more robust, since a change to the underlying table won't just break all `INSERT` statements....

Answer (score 1):

I would have to read your code that grabs the contents of the file, but it looks like you are retrieving the file contents as a string and passing them to the stored procedure. The statement is then attempting to insert a string into a binary field and failing because of the invalid datatype. In your insert statement you could do the following:

```
INSERT INTO schema.tablename
VALUES (
  @myProduct,
  @myVersion,
  @myAction,
  NULL,
  @myPath,
  CONVERT(varbinary(MAX),@myBlob),
  myDeviceType,
  @Shortname
)
```

If you do not have access to alter the insert statement you could also convert your string to a binary data-type before passing it to the stored procedure.

Another option would be to change the data type on your table from varbinary(max) to varchar(max) and then you will not have to manage any conversions.

If you really want to be slick, you can also look into Sql Server Filestreams (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb933993(v=SQL.105).aspx). Using filestreams you can pass and retrieve your file from the database. It will be stored on the file system outside of the database and the database would maintain meta data about the file internally.

Comment: Thanks.I went ahead and read the file in binary from the VB side and then passed it in that way.

Comment: Great! Glad you were able to get it working properly

Answer (score 1):

Reading your code , it seems that your are passing a `varbinary` datatype to a `varchar` column datatype. kindly check your column datatype.

If you don't want to convert the `@myBlob`, you have to make your column datatype `varbinary` too.. because you declare your variable `@myBlob` as `varbinary`.' , or you can change the datatype of your variable declaration from `varbinary` to `varchar`.

3 ways to correct it.

1. Convert your variable `@myBlob` to `varchar`:

   ```
   CONVERT(varchar(max), @myBlob) or CAST(@myBlob AS varchar(max))
   ```
2. change your column datatype from `varchar` to `varbinary`
3. change the datatype of your variable declaration to `varchar`:

   ```
   DECLARE @myBlob VARCHAR(MAX)
   ```

Regards